# Safety of storing mathematically manipulated password

Tags: password-encryption

I want to find a safe way to authenticate an user without saving the password
in order to do that I was thinking of transforming the password and storing the transformed variation within the class user.
Is it a safe way of doing so? if not what is the reason ?

Let's say our average Joe is creating an account
his username is "joe" and password "`YEe3t`"
I will use the ASCII table to simplify the example
YEe3t = (89, 69, 101, 51, 116)

my transformation function would do something similar to :

> (1*89 mod 97) + (2*69) + (3*101 mod 97) + (4*51) + (5*116 mod 97) = 538

since `YEe3t` is 5 character long it would be stored as `5538`.

When logging in if the length match + the transformation of the input in the password field thru the same function match the login will be successful

Comment: You have the right idea, but don't reinvent the wheel. Use an existing salt+hash scheme and library to do it for you. The math behind encryption is extremely hard to get right; use the math others have already figured it and have peer-reviewed.

Comment: I think your question may find better answers if asked on https://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, you don't store passwords at all. See the developer FAQ on [Plain Text Offenders](https://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs).

Answer (score 4):

I really like how you came up with hash functions intuitively. Great work!

However, please don't try to come up with an implementation by yourself - you're welcome to read [our FAQ for developers](https://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs) on the best ways to hash/store passwords.